# How do I get drivers for the web cam on my Toshiba Satellite C855?

Tags: installation, drivers, 13.04, webcam, toshiba-satellite

I am a new user to ubuntu (and linux for that matter). I am aware that a lot of my drivers and controls for the computer hardware did not re-install once I loaded ubuntu. I am curious if drivers exist for my web cam that will work with this platform and how can I install them?

Answer (score 0):

Typically the linux kernel will have drivers for most of the hardware with the odd few unsupported due to being too new in which case an updated kernel may fix that, or too few meaning it's not enough people have that particular webcam hence no driver...